# Weka NumericToNominal attributeIndices

Tags: filter, filtering, weka

I am using the Weka GUI and imported a csv file.
I want to transform a numerical attribute to nominal with the "NumericToNominal"-filter. 
There are values between "-1" and "770". 
If I set the attributeIndices value to "first-30,31-100,101-150,151-last", I get the error message: "Problem filtering instances: Invalid range list at first-30".

Do you have any idea, what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the same NumericToNominal filter because I read in a csv file from the UI and it claimed everything was numeric.

You are using the -R switch and so it is looking for the range of column numbers.  The values in whatever columns should not matter.  Columns begin at 1 or first as you have above.  The error message you get "Invalid range list" is when you reference a column number that does not exist.  Therefore, it seems to indicate that either you have less than 30 columns or one of the columns between 1 and 30 has somehow been removed..  Did you mix up column numbers with the values contained within said columns because I believe having a negative value would not be a problem for this process?